# How to properly name a service that is similar to an ActiveRecord Model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a simple question on naming conventions of services/models.

**Background:**

Currently I am developing an application which interfaces with the Soundcloud API. I created three "service" files which do all of the communicating with the soundcloud API called:

```
soundcloud_followers.rb
soudncloud_user.rb
soundcloud_query.rb
```

These services simply pull in data from the Soundcloud API. For example, the soundcloud_user.rb file is responsible for pulling in a user object from the API.

I am now storing the data in my ActiveRecord database, however, I am struggling with naming here. Initially I just wanted to call my DB tables `soundcloud_users` and `soundcloud_followers`, but then that overlaps with my service naming convention.

**My question:**

Are there any tips on naming that I could use here to make it clear that one is for storing Soundcloud data locally while another is used for accessing Soundcloud data from the API?

Comment: Just namespace them. `::Services::SoundcloudUser` has no collision with `::SoundcloudUser` (the model)

Comment: Hey Sergio - I am unfamiliar with what you mean by namespace them. I am looking into it so thanks for the suggestion. Can you provide any details on what you mean or other resources? Thanks :)

Comment: hi @gallant this is a very good question. You have probably found a solution. I guess what Sergio means is namespacing your services inside a specific module. But this topie is highly debated. You can check this post here : https://www.codewithjason.com/rails-service-objects/

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Services::Soundcloud::FetchFollowers
Services::Soundcloud::FetchUsers
```